# Browser and postman returns reults but Rest template returns 0 results due to %26

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

In my url there is query part. in Query I pass %26.
Example

```
"http://host.com/api/1/searcharticles?key=XXXXXX&query=(subject:"Polls %26 Surveys")"
```

If I run same URL in Postman or Browser then it returns me 21 results but if I run in the RestTemplate then it returns 0 results.
I believe API not able to identify %26.

I tried the same URL in the Python also and it is returning 21 results.

Sample code

```
url = "http://host.com/api/1/searcharticles?key=XXXXXX&query=(subject:"Polls %26 Surveys")";
byte[] gzipResponse = restTemplate.exchange(metabaseUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, byte[].class).getBody();
String string = new String(gzipResponse);
System.out.println(string);
```

Comment: why would you have %26 in an url?

Comment: It is part of the query. like query="subject:"polls & surveys"". As & is not working in the Java so I made it %26

Comment: You can use UriComponentBuilder to pass the parameter in the rest template. Also, you can encode them.

Answer (score 1):

Do not just use %26 for & while using RestTemplate try to use URLEncoder

```
URLEncoder.encode(your url string, "UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well 2 things

**First:**

Your url variable doesn't look correct. It should be

```
url = "http://host.com/api/1/searcharticles?key=XXXXXX&query=(subject:\"Polls %26 Surveys\")";
```

**Second:**

Your URL is encoded so you need to decode it before sending like this

```
String url = URLDecoder.decode("Polls %26 Surveys", "UTF-8");
System.out.println(url);

OUTPUT:    
Polls & Surveys
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this, you don't need to use `%26` as long as you encode your url before using.

```
    url = "http://host.com/api/1/searcharticles?key=XXXXXX&query=(subject:\"Polls & Surveys\")";
    url = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
    byte[] gzipResponse = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, byte[].class).getBody();
    String string = new String(gzipResponse);
    System.out.println(string);
```